# What kind of Time format is this?

Tags: timestamp, time-format

I know they are all from Jan 11 2019

"636824583000000000"
"636824583600000000"
"636824598000000000"
"636824598600000000"
"636824599200000000"

Examples: 
636828061800000000 = 11 Jan 19 @ 10:23 AM
636828062400000000 = 11 Jan 19 @ 10:24 AM

Comment: Determine the time interval in seconds between the values. That should be useful to determine the epoch as it is most likely a linear value of "the number of something" to the epoch. If it is not a linear scale then it is likely compound values (eg. numbers of julian days -concat- number of seconds); and even in here the two components likely follow a linear value individually. This would be easy to 'crack' if knowing the actual time for each value.

Comment: 636828061800000000 = 11 Jan 19 @ 10:23 AM ;
636828062400000000 = 11 Jan 19 @ 10:24 AM

Comment: I believe is Seconds since year 0.....

Answer (score 1):

What i could discovery is:
If we divide the number by 10000000 the output is "Seconds Since 0001-01-01 AD".

So 636828262200000000 becomes 63682826220

63682826220 = 11/01/2019 @ 15:57 GMT-02

GMT: Friday, 11 January 2019 17:57:00

My time zone: Friday, 11 January 2019 15:57:00 GMT-02:00

https://www.epochconverter.com/seconds-days-since-y0